# How to get user name and image using facebook sdk in android app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Integrated facebook sdk to my android app .i can able to successful login now i am Trying to get user id and profile picture and name.but here `String jsonUser = fb.request("me");` i am getting facebook error (tried by debugging ,facebookerror catch block executed).how to fix this.
here i am placing code after session valid.

```
if (fb.isSessionValid()) {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.logout_button);
            pic.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            JSONObject obj = null;
            URL img_url = null;

            try {
                String jsonUser = fb.request("me");
                obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);
                String id = obj.optString("id");
                String name = obj.optString("name");
                hello.setText("Welcome, " + name);
                img_url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/" + id
                        + "/picture?type=normal");
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.login_button);
            pic.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After login call this method...

```
getProfileInformation();
```

And after add below codes..

```
public void getProfileInformation() {

        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {

            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);                  
                    // getting name of the user
                    final String name = profile.getString("name");
                    // getting email of the user
                    final String email = profile.getString("email");
                        // getting email of the user
                    final String id = profile.getString("id");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email +"\nId: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });


    }
```

`public static AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = null;`

`mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);`

Comment: add above ur oncreate this line public static AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = null; and inside oncreate add this line  mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/ having problem with this tutorial

Comment: did you get the result...!

Comment: no yar ,i didn't get the solution,tried by downloading the code from above link but it is not working